# Filter a list to find strings which only contain a certain defined set of characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a list of Japanese words, and a smaller list of characters. I want to search the word list and filter it to find only words that contain characters in my character list, and nothing else. For example, if my word list is the following:

```
水曜日
火曜日
木曜日
花火
火水
日本語
```

And my character list is the following:

```
水
曜
日
火
```

I only want to return the following words:

```
水曜日
火曜日
火水
```

Because the other three words contain characters not on my list.

Currently I'm using a REGEXMATCH formula with the following regex `[水|火|曜|日]`, which captures all words that contain any of the characters, not just the words which only contain those characters.

Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[水火曜日]+$`

Ensure that between the start and end of the string, only your selected characters can appear, but can appear as many times as needed.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQl2WE/3/)

Comment: Brilliant, it works perfectly. Thanks for the lightning fast response!

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it addressed your question.

Comment: I shan't forget, but you were so quick I can't accept your response yet :')

Comment: @Lou The `^[水|火|曜|日]+$` regex also matches `|||||||||||||`. I am not sure it is your intention.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that one snuck right past me - editing my answer accordingly.